# Automatically creating a printable sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am tasked to create some Excel file to directly print out data he enters.

Its for artists, and there are two data sheets:

Sheet1:

Artist_Name Birthyear Deathyear

Example:

```
A 1900 1980
B 1902 1940
```

Sheet2:

**Artist_Name Year_of_painting Place_where_painting_is Information_on_Painting Additional**

Example:

```
A 1932 Somewhere Madonna Oil
A 1943 Otherwhere Jesus Statue
B 1923 Elsewhere God Watercolour
B 1924 Somewhere Jesus Ceiling
```

The printed page should look something like

```
A (1900-1980)
  1932 Somewhere Madonna
       Oil
  1943 Otherwhere Jesus
       Statue

B (1902-1940)
  1923 Elsewhere God
       Watercolour
-------------------------------------- (Page break)
still B
  1924 Somewhere Jesus
       Ceiling
```

How would I do that?

Comment: The very first task you need to do is club data from both sheets into one & then use Page Layout command and set Page size, Margins & Print area. If You want automation for printing you need MACRO ! ☺

Comment: What sort of macro?

Comment: VBA code to print particular data range.

Comment: You can use index() + match() --> have a try. here's some [ref](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact). Rearrange the output cell/box to fit your desired format/position.. You'll be close to what you need. IMHO vba is optional for this case.

Comment: @SinisterMJ mind sharing what you had tried but didn't/just partially work?     || given what the current Q post has. It is NOT an impossible task.. just need a little investment of keyboard and internet-ing.. You may start by including the **best** progress/tries(from Comment/links)/internet-search-results/screenshot/sampleFile of what you had made so far into the Q post...  || We can surely initiate the quest from there.. Or at least.. I will be very grateful for the effort invested. /(^_^)\